# Expo Android api request: [TypeError: Network request failed]

Tags: android, reactjs, expo, vercel

Making an api request to a nextjs site hosted on vercel from android not working

Can you help? Android api request: [TypeError: Network request failed]
I have a expo app that makes a simple fetch:

const res = await fetch(`${API_URL}/get-data`, {
method: "GET",
});
The api url is a next.js api route hosted on vercel. This works perfectly on iOS, however on andorid I keep getting this error. Interestingly If I host the next.js api locally and put it on a Ngrok the android app works perfectly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.